# Missing References Azure Blob

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage

May I ask about is that I missing any assembly references?
I not understand the error.
Thank You.
[Error in Azure Blob Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq6mV.png)

[Reference in Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeP9M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method:

```
UploadFromFileAsync("file_path");
```

is not available for the Xamarin.Forms. This is because from Xamarin.Forms you cannot have direct access to the FileSystem.

You will have to read the file then either pass the Text, ByteArray or Stream to any of the methods.

Ex: using the ByteArray:

```
await blobRef.UploadFromByteArrayAsync (byteArrayFromFile, 0, byteArrayFromFile.Length);
```

There are some post showing how to do cross-platform IO operations.

Ex: https://blog.xamarin.com/simple-cross-platform-file-io-for-ios-android-and-windows/